# Difference between ベッド and 寝台

Tags: word-choice, usage, nuances

Both of them mean bed and they target the same [wiki page](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%99%E3%83%83%E3%83%89).

I mostly see ベッド, so I guess it is the common word for bed.
In which case should I use 寝台 ?

Comment: Did you [try an image search](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=%E5%AF%9D%E5%8F%B0&client=ubuntu&hs=RVv&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=UNROVMqiFfeZsQSIoYCADg&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=648)?

Comment: I saw that earlier but it confuses me. Why one word points toward the other one (not only on wiki, but also on most dictionaries I looked into) when it is not the same thing ? According to that image search 寝台 is to be used as beds found in 寝台車 only, is it ?

Comment: Well, the definition must use other words to define it. In all cases it's a "bed" of some kind after all. It's not only used for trains: http://www.tokaikotsu.co.jp/taxi/taxi-sindaisya.html As far as I know, it's usually not a synonym for ベッド (the kind you have in your bedroom).

Comment: Great explanations. You gave me the answer I wanted !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Note that 寝る doesn't necessarily imply sleeping, but can mean "to lie down".)

寝台 is just what it says: an elevated platform (台) for lying down / sleeping (寝) and usually refers to the "bed"s in couchette/sleeping cars in trains (or buses, ships, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the upvote. Just so you know, you could wait a couple of hours/days before accepting it to see if anyone can improve on this answer. (We have a number of native speakers active on this site, which often post great answers to all sorts of questions.)